When to utilize Immutable Ids in MS Graph API
I have created a series of methods utilizing ms graph which typical return an email object with an id or a folder with an id, etc. Some example ones are as follows:
        public async Task<Models.Email?> SendEmailAsync(string mailBox, AddEmailDTO email)
    {
        var requestBody = new Message
        {
            ToRecipients = email.To?.Select(contact => new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = contact.EmailAddress,
                    Name = contact.Name
                }
            }).ToList(),
            CcRecipients = email.Cc?.Select(contact => new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = contact.EmailAddress,
                    Name = contact.Name
                }
            }).ToList(),
            BccRecipients = email.Cc?.Select(contact => new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = contact.EmailAddress,
                    Name = contact.Name
                }
            }).ToList(),
            Subject = email.Subject,
            Body = new ItemBody
            {
                ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                Content = email.Body,
            }
        };

        var result = await _graphServiceClient.Users[mailBox].Messages.PostAsync(requestBody, rc =>
        {
            rc.Headers.Add("Prefer", "IdType=\"ImmutableId\"");
        });
        
        if(result != null) 
        {
            await _graphServiceClient.Me.Messages[result.Id].Send.PostAsync(rc =>
            {
                rc.Headers.Add("Prefer", "IdType=\"ImmutableId\"");
            });
            
            return await GetEmailAsync(mailBox, result.Id!); 
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public async Task<Models.Email?> SendReplyToEmailAsync(string mailBox, string messageId, AddEmailDTO email)
    {
        var requestBody = new CreateReplyPostRequestBody
        {
            Message = new Message
            {
                ToRecipients = email.To?.Select(contact => new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = contact.EmailAddress,
                        Name = contact.Name
                    }
                }).ToList(),
                CcRecipients = email.Cc?.Select(contact => new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = contact.EmailAddress,
                        Name = contact.Name
                    }
                }).ToList(),
                BccRecipients = email.Cc?.Select(contact => new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = contact.EmailAddress,
                        Name = contact.Name
                    }
                }).ToList(),
                Subject = email.Subject,
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                    Content = email.Body,
                },
                
            },
        };

        var result = await _graphServiceClient.Users[mailBox].Messages[messageId].CreateReply.PostAsync(requestBody, rc =>
        {
            rc.Headers.Add("Prefer", "IdType=\"ImmutableId\"");
        });
        
        if(result != null) 
        {
            await _graphServiceClient.Users[mailBox].Messages[result.Id].Send.PostAsync( rc =>
            {
                rc.Headers.Add("Prefer", "IdType=\"ImmutableId\"");
            });
            return await GetEmailAsync(mailBox, result.Id!); 
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public async Task CopyEmailByFolderIdAsync(string mailBox, string messageId, string folderId)
    {
        var requestBody = new CopyPostRequestBody
        {
            DestinationId = folderId,
            
        };

        var result = await _graphServiceClient.Users[mailBox].Messages[messageId].Copy.PostAsync(requestBody, rc =>
        {
            rc.Headers.Add("Prefer", "IdType=\"ImmutableId\"");
        });
    }

    public async Task MoveEmailByFolderIdAsync(string mailBox, string messageId, string folderId)
    {
        var requestBody = new MovePostRequestBody
        {
            DestinationId = folderId,
        };

        var result = await _graphServiceClient.Users[mailBox].Messages[messageId].Move.PostAsync(requestBody, rc =>
        {
            rc.Headers.Add("Prefer", "IdType=\"ImmutableId\"");
        });
    }

My concern is I use these Ids later for instance if I send an email I need to then move it to a folder. So should I just add the ImmutableId header to every request I make as shown in these examples? Are these immutable ids there by default and this header just swaps out the usual id for the immutable id? Or did the resource need to be created with the immutable id first for them to be accessed at a later date by it?


So should I just add the ImmutableId header to every request I make as shown in these examples?

If you are going to be storing and using any mail Id then you should use ImmutableId on all your request there shouldn't be any performance penalty

Are these immutable ids there by default and this header just swaps out the usual id for the immutable id? Or did the resource need to be created with the immutable id first for them to be accessed at a later date by it?

The way the messages are stored in the Exchange Store is there is only one instance of that object (per mailbox) and then normally the id you get would be from the contents Table of the container (folder) that the message is in. When you ask for an ImmutableId your getting an identifier that the API (Microsoft Graph) can use to get to the Item regardless of the container its in as long as it is still in the same mailbox. There is a translation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-translateexchangeids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http operation that allows you to translate a regular id to a ImmutableId one but its only valid while the regularId is valid (even though the ImmutableId itself doesn't change) for example as soon as you move a message this regularId is removed from the container's contents folder.

So even for GET request should I also put the header for immutable id?

It not necessary needed as the Id won't change once you have it and if you use the ImmutableId in the Get request then the ImmutableId will be returned in the result of the Get request regardless of the header (eg its redundant).
